# RabbitMQ get message send confirm

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp

Is it possible in RabbitMQ to get confirm messages, when I send to queue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use the [return listener](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v2.8.4/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-2.8.4/com/rabbitmq/client/ReturnListener.html) and mandatory flag on [basic publish](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v2.8.4/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-2.8.4/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#basicPublish%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.BasicProperties,%20byte%5B%5D%29)

Comment: I want just check, if message from convertAndSend method was delivered

Comment: what do you mean by delivered.  If you use the mandatory flag and the return listener it should tell you that the message was delivered to the consumer.