# RabbitMQ - Optionally create additional message?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have two scripts which generate messages in one queue, one of the scripts would like the queue to generate an additional message once the message has been successfully ack'd - note this is not RPC I want to do additional processing optionally once the first message has completed successfully, but until the first message has been processed successfully I cannot do the second round of processing.

Does anyone have any experience doing this? My initial thought is to send additional parameters to the initial message identifying the "next steps" but this seems a little hackish so I was hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

check my answer to this question:
[RabbitMQ get message send confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652368/rabbitmq-get-message-send-confirm)

This functionality should allow you to do what you want.

Comment: That isn't quite what I'm after - that seems to be more RPC based (ie submit X and Receive Y and do Z) - I'm after Do X and optionally queue additional tasks following the task's completion (not necessarily one, could be 10 for instance).

Comment: the return listener will tell the producer (possibly a different thread from the one that is publishing) that the message has been delivered, then you can do what ever you want.  The return listener thread will need to have a rule that decides what it wants to do once it had receive and acknowledgement of the arrival of the last message.

Comment: Not sure if I explained this well enough, apologies. I might have 2+ scripts which generate messages for execution at a later time (ie these might be user scripts, so there won't be a "wait" possible, as the thread will be stopped). Some of these messages will then need to be sent on to other scripts to add further processing, but its optional not all messages will need further processing. I would prefer the consuming script to create more messages for other queues - but whats the best approach to indicate to the script that it needs to optionally pass this on?